# Getting error while adding the Microsoft.Azure.Document.Core reference in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform, azure-cosmosdb

I am working with Xamarin cross platform application, while I am trying to add the reference from NuGet Package Manger I am getting an error like :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 1.3.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assumed that you are developing the Xamarin.Forms application. If you add `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` package into your PCL project, you would retrieve the error message as you mentioned.

You need to add the [DocumentDB Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core) NuGet package into the specific platform projects in your Xamarin.Forms solution. For more details, you could refer to [Consuming an Azure Cosmos DB Document Database](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/cosmosdb/consuming/).

Comment: Thanks, that's working. But how can I call the methods written in portable project to specific platform project ?

Comment: You could define the documentdb operations interface in your PCL project, then implement this interface in your platform-specific projects. And you could leverage the `DependencyService` class in your PCL project to invoke Azure DocumentDB Client Library code contained in platform-specific projects. Here is a sample about how to use `DependencyService`, you could refer to [Dependency Service](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/DependencyService/DependencyServiceSample).